# Save structure function leaves a spare place in a file instead of writing an array

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct BirdHome{
  char area[500];
  char heightcm[100];
  char feederquantity[10];
  char hasNest[5];
};
struct Bird{
  char isRinged[5];
  char nameSpecies[50];
  char birdAgeMonths[500];
  struct BirdHome hom;
  char gender[6];
};
struct Bird birds;

int main(void){
  FILE *oput;
  int max=100;
  int count = 0;
  char filename[100];
  printf("file name? : ");
  scanf("%s", &filename);
  count = load(filename, &birds, max);
    if (count == 0)
      printf("No structures loaded\n");
    else (
      printf("Data loaded\n")
    );
  save(&birds, oput);
  return 0;
}


int load(char *filename, struct Bird *birds, int max){
int count = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
char line[100 * 4];
  if (fp == NULL)
    return 1;
  while (count < max && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
    sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", birds[count].isRinged, birds[count].nameSpecies,
    birds[count].birdAgeMonths, birds[count].hom.area,
    birds[count].hom.heightcm, birds[count].hom.feederquantity,
    birds[count].hom.hasNest,birds[count].gender);
    count++;
  }
fclose(fp);
return count;
}


int save (struct Bird *birds, FILE *oput){
  int i;
  oput=fopen("birdssave.txt","w");
  for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  fprintf(oput,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",birds[i].isRinged, birds[i].nameSpecies,
  birds[i].birdAgeMonths, birds[i].hom.area,
  birds[i].hom.heightcm, birds[i].hom.feederquantity,
  birds[i].hom.hasNest,birds[i].gender);
  }
  fclose(oput);
}
```

Well, the problem was said in the description of the question. Somehow, the load function works properly (at least I think so, because it runs properly and the success message is always displayed) and the save function runs without errors, but it doesn't write the needed info inside a file and just leaves gaps.

```
True sparrow 3 30 20 2 False Male
False crane 24 200 100 6 True Female
False griffin 14 300 80 1 False Male
```

This is a text file which my program used to write and load. I think this can somehow help you to find my mistakes in this code.

Comment: You are lucky program is running : You have only 1 bird in birds. Birds should be an array of Bird (struct Bird birds[100] for example) and the when you load/save you use 'birds' not '&birds'

Comment: Thank you fro the answer. i tried to do what you've said: changed the struct Bird birds to struct Bird birds[100] and deleted the & symbols in calls of functions. that, unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: If fully used, a single bird can occupy a smidgen under 1200 bytes of data.  You can't reliably read 1200 bytes into a line of only 400 bytes.  Either change the 500's in your structures to some smaller number, or increase the size of your line to at least `sizeof(struct Bird)`.  It isn't clear why the age in months would ever require a 500 character mini-essay (with no spaces in the text) — that should probably be reduced to perhaps 20, if you're feeling generous.

Comment: You should check the return value from `sscanf()` to ensure that all the fields were read.  Because you're using `%s` for the conversion specifications, you cannot have any spaces in any of the strings.  This may be tenable to start with, but many bird species have multiple words in the name ("great crested warbler", etc), so you'd have to deal with 'how to read strings with spaces' using `sscanf()`.  And you'd probably need some character other than space to separate fields in the file format.

Comment: Although I just went through your code, I could load the file and save it, by just fixing the warnings

Comment: Jonathan Leffler,thank you for the answer. i'll surely try to do what you've suggested

Comment: Note that storing `False` in the `is_ringed` element of the structure requires `char is_ringed[6]` — you must allow for the null byte.  If you read the ringed value after the species name and the value was false, you'd zap the first byte of the species name with a null byte, which would leave the species name 'empty'.  You probably don't see this effect since the species is read after the ringed status, but that means you'd get "Falsesparrow" as the ringed status for an unringed sparrow; the species value would zap the null byte terminating the ringed status.  Beware undefined behaviour!

Comment: Note these are comments, not answers.  Just a terminological phenomenon on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load function is made unproperly so it doesn't work. The normal functions does a lot more things to do. Here is the text of it with the needed commentaries

```
int load(char * filename){
  FILE * fp;
  char *c;
  int m = sizeof(int);
  int n, i;
  /*prepare memory for info*/
  int *pti = (int *)malloc(m);
  if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
    perror("Error occured while opening file");
    return 1;
  }
  /*read the quantity of structures*/
  c = (char *)pti;
  while (m>0){
    i = getc(fp);
    if (i == EOF) break;
    *c = i;
    c++;
    m--;
  }
  /*get the number of elements*/
  n = *pti;
  /*prepare memory for read massive of structures*/
  struct bird * ptr = (struct bird *) malloc(3 * sizeof(struct bird));
  c = (char *)ptr;
  /*after save we read massive by symbols*/
  while ((i= getc(fp))!=EOF){
    *c = i;
    c++;
  }
  /*sort the elements and printing in console*/
  printf("\n%d birds in the file stored\n\n", n);
  for (int k = 0; k<n; k++){
    printf("%d %s %s %d %d %d %d %s %s  \n", k + 1,
     ptr[k].isRinged,ptr[k].nameSpecies,ptr[k].birdAgeMonths,ptr[k].homearea,
     ptr[k].homeheightcm,ptr[k].homefeederquantity,ptr[k].homehasNest,ptr[k].gender);
  }
  free(pti);
  free(ptr);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

At least, the save function can be untouched only because algorhytmically it does the same as the normal code.